# React application with different timers on different buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, optimization, timer

We have two types of timer buttons, This information we are getting from the client configuration file.

1. Variable timer: It will configured with one time value.
   For example: Can be between 100ms, 200ms, ... up to 60 mins.
   Button click Behavior: Let's say we got a time value of 8 seconds for this button.
   For ex> If someone clicks on this type of button it will move to the ON state and stay in that state for 8 seconds. and then it will go to OFF state.
2. Circular timer button: This type of button has a maximum 3 states { Off, Press1, Press2 }
   You can set time for Press1 state and Press2, As it is a circular button it will toggle between both Press1 and Press2 as per the time given to them.
   **Button click Behavior**: let say we have set the time for Press1 900ms and Press2 100ms. If someone clicks on the button it will move to the Press1 state and it will hold the Press1 state for 900ms. and After 900ms it will move to Press2 state it will hold there for 100ms in Press2 state and move back to Press1 state and this cycle continues until someone is off that button.

In this application, each state contains some operations to do in the application.

Button1 type variable timer time 8 seconds.
Operations: On ON state, it will put Button2 to Press1 state and Button3 to state 8
On the OFF state, it will make buttons Button2 and Button 3 OFF after 8 seconds.
Button2 type circular: Press1 time 900ms, Press2 100ms
Operation: On Press1 state no operations, On Press2 state will move Button3 to one state down from the current state.

For better understanding

[use case detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAwJ8.png)

[current behavior in application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCnyM.gif)
**ISSUE we are facing.**
When configuring the above Scenario for the Button1 countdown timer there is lag/delay, which is making the timers are timing out early.
Button 3 is not going to its very first state and gets terminated before that. because Button1 8 second time is over and it moves to OFF state making Button2 and Button3 to OFF state.

How to make it work in sync to handle the lag/delay?

```
#TimerComponent 
 let buttonTimer = null;
 useEffect(() => {
    if (activeTimerData.length > 0) {
      clearTimeout(buttonTimer);
      startTimer(activeTimerData[0]);
    } else {
      clearTimeout(buttonTimer);
    }
  }, [activeTimerData]);

  const startTimer = async (obj) => {
    const timeoutTime = obj.buttonTimertime - Date.now();
    let type = obj?.buttonData?.controlHeadType;
    buttonTimer = setTimeout(async () => {
      await changeStatesOfInputsTimer(obj?.buttonData, obj.statIndex, type); // Perform all the other binding state operations.
      console.log(timeoutTime, obj?.buttonData, 'timeout');
    }, timeoutTime);
  };
 
  #Common Functions
  export const setSecurityTimer = (buttonData, statIndex) => {
    securityTimerArray = getactiveTimerData();
    securityTimerArray = securityTimerArray.filter((obj) => obj.virtualInputId !== buttonData.virtualInputId);
    if (buttonData.inputType !== 'cyclic') {
      let btnData = {};
      btnData.buttonData = buttonData;
      btnData['buttonTimertime'] = Date.now() + buttonData.timer;
      btnData['statIndex'] = statIndex;
      btnData['virtualInputId'] = buttonData.virtualInputId;
      securityTimerArray.push(btnData);
    } else {
      let btnData = {};
      btnData.buttonData = buttonData;
      btnData['virtualInputId'] = buttonData.virtualInputId;
      if (statIndex === 2) {
        statIndex = statIndex - 1;
        btnData['statIndex'] = statIndex;
        btnData['buttonTimertime'] = Date.now() + buttonData.timerPress2;
        securityTimerArray.push(btnData);
      } else if (statIndex === 1) {
        statIndex = statIndex + 1;
        btnData['statIndex'] = statIndex;
        btnData['buttonTimertime'] = Date.now() + buttonData.timer;
        securityTimerArray.push(btnData);
      }
    }
  
    securityTimerArray = securityTimerArray.sort((x, y) => x.buttonTimertime - y.buttonTimertime);
    // Call action to update state of active Timer Data
    store.dispatch(setSecurityTimerData(securityTimerArray));
  };

  #On each click creating timer data using below Code
  let securityTimerArray = []; 
  let timerInputIndex = buttonData.clickState
  if (buttonData && (buttonData.inputType === 'variable' || buttonData.inputType === 'cyclic')) {
    securityTimerArray = getactiveTimerData(); // current active timer data from store.
    if (buttonData.inputType !== 'cyclic') {
      if (timerInputIndex) {
        let statIndex = timerInputIndex - 1;
        setSecurityTimer(buttonData, statIndex);
      } else {
        // removing button from securityTimeArray for OFF state
      }
    } else {
      if (timerInputIndex) {
        setSecurityTimer(buttonData, timerInputIndex);
      } else {
        // removing button from securityTimeArray for OFF state
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hello, it's a bit hard to follow, can you rewrite in a simple words what you have and what is expected? Maybe with one button

Answer (score 0):

If it's not expected to share state between buttons than timers should be inside of the button.

Button example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
    
    // Enum for button states
    const ButtonStates = {
      OFF: 'OFF',
      ON: 'ON'
    };
    
    const TimerButton = ({ duration = 5000, onText = 'ON', offText = 'OFF', onStateChange }) => {
      const [buttonState, setButtonState] = useState(ButtonStates.OFF);
      const [timer, setTimer] = useState(null);
    
      const handleClick = () => {
        clearTimeout(timer);  // Clear any existing timer
    
      
          setButtonState(ButtonStates.ON);
          const newTimer = setTimeout(() => {
            setButtonState(ButtonStates.OFF);
            // Fire the event after state change
            onStateChange && onStateChange(ButtonStates.OFF);
          }, duration);
          setTimer(newTimer);
          // Fire the event after state change
          onStateChange && onStateChange(ButtonStates.ON);
        
      };
    
      return (
        <button onClick={handleClick}>
          {buttonState === ButtonStates.OFF ? offText : onText}
        </button>
      );
    };
    
    export default TimerButton;
```

Example of a call:

```
    <TimerButton 
  duration={5000} 
  onText="Activated" 
  offText="Deactivated" 
  onStateChange={(state) => console.log(`Button state changed to: ${state}`)} 
/>
```